# Should you make a blessing over the spices if you temporarily can't smell?

Tags: blessing, havdalah, smell

It is customary to make a blessing before smelling spices during the Havdalah ceremony at the end of Shabbat.  I have read this is supposed to lighten the end of Shabbat and give a pleasant smell to the new week.

Generally, we have a rule to say a blessing before enjoying some part of creation, however if one cannot smell temporarily, say due to a bad cold, then he is not getting anything from the spices and it makes me wonder if he should refrain from making the blessing at all rather than make a *bracha levalata*. You might not be completely certain if you will be able to smell them, providing some wiggle room, but if you *know* you have no sense of smell right now, would it be better to just skip directly from the blessing over wine to the blessing over fire?